# Subsetting of data frame in R with row selection

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have two data frames. One named "discovery" is like

```
probeID         symbol  is.TF   entrezID
ILMN_1814092    AACSP1  FALSE   729522
ILMN_1668851    AADACL4 FALSE   343066
ILMN_1805104    ABAT    FALSE   18
ILMN_2070570    ABCA10  FALSE   10349
ILMN_2232084    ABCA11P FALSE   79963
ILMN_1704579    ABCA13  FALSE   154664
ILMN_1722286    ABCA5   FALSE   23461
ILMN_1701551    ABCA6   FALSE   23460
ILMN_1743205    ABCA7   FALSE   10347
```

Another one named "values" is like

```
probeID         value   
ILMN_1814092    1.0 
ILMN_1668851    1.9 
ILMN_1805104    1.8 
ILMN_2070570    1.8 
ILMN_2232084    1.5 
ILMN_1704579    2.3 
ILMN_1722286    2.6 
ILMN_1701551    0.1 
ILMN_1743205    5.5
```

Two data frames overlap in terms of row "probeID"

How can I select from "discovery" where the "probeID" appeared in "values" ?

```
overlap <- discovery[values$probeID,]
```

It gives me a data frame with all values are **NA**

Answer (score 0):

If you need a dataset with columns `values` , `merge` is the better way. But if you just need to get subset of `discovery` where `probeID` appears. The following works.

```
overlap <- discovery[discovery$probeID %in% values$probeID,]
```

`%in%` operator is based on match, so here I am selecting only rows where `discovery$probeID` matches any of `values$probeID`

Comment: It works but things got wrong, it is supposed to give me 2000 observations, but it only gives 1942 observations.

Comment: @ToBeGeek, have to look at full data, it should give all observation if present.

Comment: The discovery in txt file is very big, I use fread to get the data frame

Comment: @Ananta All my friends got 2000 observation, but the above command just return 1942

Comment: lol, your friends may be wrong. Can you give us output of following. `class(discovery$probeID), class(value$probeID), length(values$probeID), length(unique(values$probeID)), length(intersect(discovery$probeID,value$probeID))`

Comment: @ToBeGeek, I do not know about `fread()`. why not just `read.table()`..and please, give me the output of above

Comment: The dataset is big, read.table() crashed my RStudio, thats why I use fread.

Comment: class(discovery$probeID)="character", class(value$probeID)="character"，

Comment: and output of those `length`, those are key in determining how much will you have

Comment: Yes, you are right @Ananta, they report 1942 rather than 2000, I guess something wrong with fread

Answer (score 0):

Just do`merge(discovery, values, by.x = "probeID", by.y = "probeID")`

Brief explanations, see http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html.

```
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),
     by.x = by, by.y = by, all = FALSE, all.x = all, all.y = all,
     sort = TRUE, suffixes = c(".x",".y"),
     incomparables = NULL, ...)
```

merge `x` and `y`, two data frame together. If you want, you can specify the columns by which the two dataframes should be merged, using `by.x` and `by.y` respectively. If the column name is shared between `x` and `y`, then just `by=` is enough. If `by=` is not specified, then it is defaulted to the intersection of `names(x)` and `names(y)`, or the columns that are shared between the two dataframes.

Comment: if both dataset have same column, just `by="probeID" is enough no need to duplicate with `by.x = "probeID", by.y = "probeID"`

Comment: And in fact, here the default for `by` is correct and thus no `by` argument is needed.

Comment: Yes, quite right. I was trying to be general. `by.x = "probeID", by.y = "probeID"` is clearly redundant. Thanks for add the clarifications.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, I thought default `by` was `rownames`, that is interesting, always something new to know even in basic stuffs

Comment: Sorry, the two datasets do not have the same column, one got 1000 columns, another one only got 4 columns.